# Macro (loop) functions in SAS

Tags: macros, sas, proc

I am doing some very simple analysis in SAS, finding mean, standard deviation and median, and the code is like

```
proc means data=data001
mean median;
VAR= price volume; 
output out=new001;
mean=avprice avvolume
median=medprice medvolume; run;
```

But the thing is that I have more than 100 dataset (data001 to data299).

I just want to use `Macro` to process all datasets at once (from 001 to 299) and output result into one table ? Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks and have a good weekend!

Answer (score 2):

Append them all to one table and use a CLASS or BY variable to differentiate.

```
Data combined;
Set data001-data099 indsname=source;
Data_source=source;
Run;

Proc sort data=combined; by data_source; 

proc means data=combined noprint;
By data_source;
VAR= price volume; 
output out=new001;
mean=avprice avvolume
median=medprice medvolume; run;
```

Comment: It would probably be faster to create a view to combine the tables, and then use `by data_source notsorted;` for the `proc means`, as this would avoid the sort.